# How to do Prototpye inherit in odoo

Tags: odoo

i suppose I've not fully undrestood the prototype inheritance in Odoo.
I try to inherit crm.lead

The Model :

```
`    class learn_odoo(models.Model):
_name = 'learn_odoo.learn_odoo'
_inherit = ['crm.lead']
_description = 'learn_odoo.learn_odoo'
tag_ids = fields.Many2many('mail.channel','mail_channel_profile_crm', 'partner_id', 'tag_id')
job = fields.Char()`
```

The View :

```
    `<record id="view_inherit_list_crm" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Learn Odoo</field>
        <field name="model">learn_odoo.learn_odoo</field>
        <field eval="1" name="priority"/>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_tree_view_oppor"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="after">
                <field name="job"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="learn_odoo.action_window" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Learn Odoo</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">learn_odoo.learn_odoo</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>`
```

The problem I encountered :

[image]

Comment: There are probably some computed fields on `crm.lead` which will compute by using `crm.lead` records. So if you want to use the prototype inheritance you have to solve those issues one-by-one.

Comment: Oh and in most cases i would discourage inheriting `crm.lead` this way, because of the complexity behind that model, which in most parts will be inherited, too, and can lead to a lot of these issues.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, what i understood is you are trying to inherit `crm.lead` if i am right then please remove the `_name = 'learn_odoo.learn_odoo'`

you have to do as i am doing below:

```
class learn_odoo(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    tag_ids = fields.Many2many('mail.channel','mail_channel_profile_crm', 'partner_id', 'tag_id', string='Tag')
    job = fields.Char('Job')
```

also in `__manifest__.py` file add crm in depends.

If you are not clear about inheritance please go through the odoo docs for inheritance from this [Link for inheritance](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/13_inheritance.html) select your `odoo version` from top right corner for better results.

Comment: No, he is using the "prototype inheritance" as you could've seen in the link you've mentioned. So giving the inherited model a new name is the right thing to do.